# regex exclude lines with first word ending in colon

Tags: regex, sed, grep

I'm trying to strip out lines that have the format

```
word: bla bla
anotherword: bla bla
```

but I want to keep

```
this example: bla bla
```

I tried this:
`cat "myfile" | grep -v "\w: "`

but that removes all lines with any word: combination

if I do this
`cat "myfile" | grep -v "^\w: "`

to say, only lines where the pattern is at the beginning, it doesn't exclude any of the lines

I also tried
`cat "myfile" | sed '/^\w:/d'`
but that didn't work either

if I try it with a specific word like 
`cat "myfile" | sed '/^title:/d'`

that works the way its supposed to.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `grep -vE '^[_[:alnum:]]+:' file`?

Comment: Yes! Thank you - That works!!  Any chance you can explain why that works but the other way didn't?

Comment: For your information, see [that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
grep -vE '^[_[:alnum:]]+:' file
```

It matches any lines but (due to `-v` option) those that

- `^` - start with
- `[_[:alnum:]]+` - 1 or more alphanumeric or `_` chars
- `:` - a colon.

Note that `\w`, which may be replaced with `[_[:alnum:]]` if supported, just matches a single word character.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/^\w+:(\s|$)/d' file
```

This would strip out lines of single words ending in a colon only or single words ending in a colon followed by a white space.